# Reading files in android two-lines at one cycle

Tags: android, file

I am trying to read a file line by line in Android.

Let's say that the first two lines are key-value pair and the third-fourth lines are another key value pair and so one until the end of the file.

How can i read two lines at once in a single cycle so i can store as key value in a hashmap?

The code I'm currently using:

```
InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(TEST_FILE_NAME);
if (instream != null) {
  InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
  BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
  String line;
  do {
    line = buffreader.readLine(); // do something with the line
  } while (line != null);
}
```

Comment: Call `readLine` twice in the loop.

Comment: Can you show me a simple example?

Comment: Show us how you read line per line, so we can help you adjust that code.

Comment: InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(TEST_FILE_NAME);
                if (instream != null) {
                    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
                    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

                    String line;

                    do {
                        line = buffreader.readLine();
                        // do something with the line
                    } while (line != null);

                }

Answer (score 0):

Taking your loop, and adding a call to `processKeyValue(String, String)` which handles the line processing, something like this should work:

```
InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(TEST_FILE_NAME);
InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
String key, value;
do {
  key = buffreader.readLine();
  if(key != null) {
    value = buffreader.readLine();

    processKeyValue(key, value); // Note that value may be null.
  }
} while (key != null && value != null);
```

I have also removed your `if` statement, since `instream` will never be `null` directly after it is created.

Comment: Thanks for the help Niek. I was trying to read a file from Dropbox but i cannot seem to figure out even with your code. How can i put the DbxFile testFile = dbxFsb.open(testPath);                   resultData = testFile.readString(); to the  InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(TEST_FILE_NAME);
                InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
                BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader); so it reads the file from Dropbox?

Comment: Anyone that can help  me?